# Appending data to previous row of a CSV using Python

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv

I'm working on a Python script that takes Nessus data exported as CSV and removes duplicate data, however due to the way the exporting works results for different ports and protocols have their own unique row, even though all the other data in the row is the same. I need to remove these duplicates, but I want to keep the Port and Protocol column data and append it to the previous row.

Here is a very small CSV I'm using to test and build the script:

[Screenshot of CSV File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luhSI.png)

As you can see all fields are the exact same apart from the port field and sometimes the protocol field will be different too, so I need to read both rows of the CSV file and then append the port like this: 80, 443 and the same with protocol: tcp, tcp

Then only save the one line to remove duplicate data, I have tried doing this by checking if there has already been an instance of the Plugin ID, however my output is only printing the second rows Port and Protocol.

```
protocollist = []
portlist = []
pluginid_list = []
multiple = False 

with open(csv_file_input, 'rb') as csvfile:
    nessusreader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in nessusreader:
        pluginid = row['Plugin ID']
        if pluginid != '':
            pluginid_list.append(row['Plugin ID'])
            print(pluginid_list)
        count = pluginid_list.count(pluginid)
        cve = row['CVE']
        if count > 0:
            protocollist.append(row['Protocol'])
            print(protocollist)
            portlist.append(row['Port'])
            print(portlist)
            print('Counted more than 1')
            multiple = True
        if multiple == True:
            stringlist = ', '.join(protocollist)
            newstring1 = stringlist
            protocol = newstring1
            stringlist2 = ', '.join(portlist)
            newstring2 = stringlist2
            port = newstring2
        else:
            protocol = row['Protocol']
            port = row['Port']
        cvss = row['CVSS']
        risk = row['Risk']
        host = row['Host']
        name = row['Name']
        synopsis = row['Synopsis']
        description = row['Description']
        solution = row['Solution']
        seealso = row['See Also']
        pluginoutput = row['Plugin Output']

with open(csv_file_output, 'w') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['Plugin ID', 'CVE', 'CVSS', 'Risk', 'Host', 'Protocol', 'Port', 'Name', 'Synopsis', 'Description', 'Solution', 'See Also', 'Plugin Output']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow({'Plugin ID': pluginid, 'CVE': cve, 'CVSS': cvss, 'Risk': risk, 'Host': host, 'Protocol': protocol, 'Port': port, 'Name': name, 'Synopsis': synopsis, 'Description': description, 'Solution': solution, 'See Also': seealso, 'Plugin Output': pluginoutput})
```

There are probably a few errors in the code as I've been trying different things, but just wanted to show the code I've been working on to give more context to the issue. This code works if the data is only as shown in the CSV as there are only two items, however I introduced a third set of data with a different Plugin ID and it then added that to the list also, probably due to the if statement being set to > 0.

Comment: please provide sample as text file, not image. So we can copy-paste.

Comment: Uploaded the CSV file so you can take a look at it: [link]http://www77.zippyshare.com/v/q6lA3YbH/file.html

Comment: Given this input, what is the output you expect ? Plus, what is the key (group of fields) to identify duplicates ?

Comment: you definitly have to visit https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask